# Wordpress, a good search plugin?

Tags: search, plugins, wordpress, plural

I'm looking for Wordpress plugin that just improved the search results, but doesn't add the the search box.

At the moment wordpress isn't even doing plurals. So does anyone know a good plugin that will make the search a whole lot better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using below plugins...

Use Relevanssi Plugin for Multilingual Support 
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/

Use WPSearch for well behave custom Search
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpsearch/

Use Search-Everything for all type of Content Search
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/

Answer (score 3):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/ does full text, fuzzy match, partial match and supports quotes and category searches. It rebuilds its index after each post/page is added.

Comment: +1 For the tip. Now I’m going to replace Search Unleashed, which stopped working with WP 3.0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for a WordPress Search Plugin that not only makes your website fully searchable but also searches through the content of attached files including PDF, DOC, DOCX and other formats are supported. Here is the solution of it https://fulltextsearch.org/. I recommend you to use that plugin.